# How to write TFRecords in a Kaggle notebook?

Tags: python, tensorflow, kaggle, tfrecord, tpu

I am currently trying to use Kaggle TPUs with the cifar10 dataset. The following code shows how I encode the data in TFRecords, but I have now idea how to store them in a file afterwards.

```
def _bytes_feature(value):
    """Returns a bytes_list from a string / byte"""
    if isinstance(value, type(tf.constant(0))):
        value = value.numpy() # BytesList won't unpack a string from an EagerTensor (what??)
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list = tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def _float_feature(value):
    """Returns a float_list from a float / double"""
    return tf.train.Feature(float_list = tf.train.FloatList(value=[value]))

def _int64_feature(value):
    """"Returns an int64_list from a bool / enum / int / uint"""
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list = tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))

def image_example(image, label, dimension):
    feature = {
        'dimension': _int64_feature(dimension),
        'label': _int64_feature(label),
        'image_raw': _bytes_feature(image.tobytes()),
    }
    return tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
```

And to write the data in TFRecords:

```
record_file = './cifar10.tfrecords'
n_samples = x_train.shape[0]
dimension = x_train.shape[1]
depth = x_train.shape[3]
# print(x_train.shape)

with tf.io.TFRecordWriter(record_file) as writer:
   for i in range(n_samples):
      image = x_train[i]
      label = y_train[i]
      tf_example = image_example(image, label, dimension) # function defined above
      writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString()) # serializes the input to store the data
```

Now I suppose I only have to run this to get my data:

```
data = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(record_file)
```

And if I try to parse the records I get the following error:

> UnimplementedError: File system scheme '[local]' not implemented (file: './cifar10.tfrecords')

But instead it just does nothing (and actually reinitializes the Kaggle session, as if I had not run anything before). Do you have any idea of the error I'm doing?

Thank you very much for any help you can come up with!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UnimplementedError: File system scheme '[local]' not implemented (file: './cifar10.tfrecords').

This is because Cloud TPU cannot write (or access to) files on Kaggle/Colab file system, it needs files to be placed on google bucket.

https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/troubleshooting#cannot_use_local_filesystem